# Error in starting hyperledger fabric network with hyperledger composer

Tags: npm, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to set up a network using hyper ledger composer, for which I followed the 
[Developer tutorial for creating a Hyperledger Composer solution](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial)
but when I use the command

```
composer network start --networkName tutorial-network --networkVersion
0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card
```

It is giving the following error :

```
Starting business network tutorial-network at version 0.0.1

Processing these Network Admins:    userName: admin

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
**Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.** Response from attempted peer comms was an error: **Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "npm ERR!** code EAI_AGAIN npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/composer-runtime-hlfv1 failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-04-10T10_10_13_361Z-debug.log " Command failed
```

I have tried tearing down the fabric and starting the fabric again but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

1. Are you behind a proxy / firewall ? If so in the `composer network install` command you require a `-o npmrcFile` parameter, to resolve the NPM registry. eg `registry=https://mycompanynpmregistry.com:4873` (or the resolved IP address) as in `composer network install -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -a digitalproperty-network.bna -o npmrcFile=/tmp/npmrcFile`  . See https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/connector-information
2. If you are finding that you get a REQUEST_TIMEOUT on a start or upgrade request, you could try increasing the timeout of the fabric default for startup timeout.

If you are using our simple Hyperledger Composer [development server environment](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html) from `composer-tools` github repo,  then you can add the following to the peer definition to see if it addresses the problem:

- CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=1200s

in the file `~/fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer/docker-compose.yml`
eg, the above is a snippet from the peer definition. You would have to do a `docker-compose stop` - then `docker-compose start` from that directory location to take effect.

Footnote:

In addition to CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT change above - you MUST ALSO UPDATE the timeout values to match (ie CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT), in the `connection.json` file for the card(s) that performs the composer network start command (eg. PeerAdmin card in $HOME/.composer). You will see 4 timeouts (3 for a Peer and 1 for the Order) in the 'client' section, under the stanza "connection". By default, these are set to 300 seconds - Increase the value to `1200` for each. Do note that CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT must have the 'trailing s' , whereas these 4 timeouts defined above - don't have this.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** I had the same error while starting the network. This solution helped me: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3591#issuecomment-386718739

It states the following:

> There is an extra character when you copy the string from hyperledger
>   composer website.
>
> Try copy pasting the following line to a notepad and paste in the
>   command line. It will work.
>
> `composer network start --networkName tutorial-network
>   --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card`

**2)** If it doesn't help, then try to kill any stale or active docker containers.

**Run the following command to kill any stale or active containers:**

> docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)

**Clear any cached networks:**

Press `y` when prompted by the command

> docker network prune

Then, go to `~/fabric-dev-servers` folder and run the commands:

> cd ~/fabric-dev-servers
>
> ./teardownFabric.sh
>
> ./startFabric.sh
>
> ./createPeerAdminCard.sh

After that, run the composer network install command:

> composer network start --networkName tutorial-network --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card

Answer (score 0):

I had same error, I found out that the pre-requisities that I have already installed in my system didnot matched the versions. So I uninstalled the pre-requisities and reinstalled them. In my case the version of docker was creating a problem.