# composer network upgrade not working when there is not internet connection

Tags: hyperledger-composer

In my production environment, there is no INTERNET connection. I want to know how I will upgrade a business network using "composer network upgrade" command. I am getting getting following error while running "composer network upgrade". [image]

Same command successfully run, when machine is having Internet connection. Please help me out, how to configure composer to work in offline mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(It looks like you are using v0.18.2 or v0.19 of composer and I assume you have Fabeic 1.1 GA)

When you run a `composer network upgrade` or `composer network start`  Fabric tries to build a new chaincode Container which includes `npm install` commands, and the error you are seeing looks like an npm install failure.

There are other Answers on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751259/error-in-starting-hyperledger-fabric-network-with-hyperledger-composer/49758354#49758354) that explain how to use an npmrc file with Composer to get around proxy problems, but if your machine is really isolated you may need to use something like [Verdaccio](http://www.verdaccio.org/) to create a private npm repository.

You will see more details of your error if you look in the Log of the Peer container.

Comment: I'm seeing `composer-common composer-runtime composer-runtime-hlfv1` .  There are many dependencies too.  If this doesn't get you a fast result, can I suggest looking at a test system which does have access to the internet, and then examining the chaincode container?