# Error trying to start business network. Last error was Error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Trying to connect an http1.x server

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Hi I am trying to run developer tutorial on hyperledger-composer from https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html

I have setup the development environment successfully.

I receive the following error

Error trying to start business network. Error: Unable to initalize 
  channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: Error: 14 
  UNAVAILABLE: Trying to connect an http1.x server

while I run the following command

composer network start --networkName tutorial-network --networkVersion 
 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card 
 PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card

I have checked the fabric is running and is listening to business network archive

"Listing Business Network Archive from tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna
  Identifier:tutorial-network@0.0.1
  Name:tutorial-network
  Version:0.0.1
  Command succeeded"

P.S I am behind firewall/proxy

Configuration
Node  @8.11.3
composer @0.19
Mac OS High Sierra

Comment: please post your full output / logs from the `composer network start` command to enable someone to help you. Its most likely you will need to do steps as identified in the answer ( item 1 ) from this S/O answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751259/error-in-starting-hyperledger-fabric-network-with-hyperledger-composer/49758354#497583544

Comment: Hi Paul. The error I mentioned is the output of composer network start.

Comment: Not sure if your proxy is causing resolution issues here, what does your connection.json file show? As mentioned, it may be your need to add an npmrcFile on the `composer network install` command to build correctly.

Comment: Hi Paul, I followed the link you sent me and now I receive a new error  Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: timeout expired while starting chaincode tutorial-network:0.0.1

Comment: Hi Paul. In connection.json there are localhost urls which are unavailable for example http://localhost:7054 throws 404