# Node API failing with Error : EHOSTUNREACH

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

```
ERRO 8dc [composerchannel][a68ccd16] failed to invoke chaincode name:"tryme" , error: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "npmERR! code EHOSTUNREACH
npm ERR! errno EHOSTUNREACH
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/composer-common failed, reason: connect EHOSTUNREACH 104.16.18.35:443

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-08-08T10_52_34_967Z-debug.log
```

I get this error on my NodeJS API, when I open docker logs I find this error was the part of Peer Container.

What I understand from this error is Hyperledger is trying to ping the URL 104.16.18.35:443, which is been blocked by my firewall as per my understanding.

But the bigger Question is If my network is internally setup then why Docker Container is trying to Ping this IP.

Comment: if you're doing a Composer business network install/start it will try to get the relevant Composer npm modules to install (as it suggests, as I think you know that the 104 address is registry.npmjs.org?)  to build the chaincode container for the business network (presumably called 'tryme') - see more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751259/error-in-starting-hyperledger-fabric-network-with-hyperledger-composer/49758354#49758354 and in the wiki https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#information_source--composer-network-start-issues

Comment: as suggested there, you need an `npmrcFile` on the `composer network install` command so that Composer knows how to reach the npm registry