# Hyperledger composer to start a business network

Tags: docker, npm, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I do a hyperledger composer deploying a business network, after running this this command `composer network start --networkName tutorial-network --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card`, I get this error:

> Starting business network definition. This may take a minute... Error:
>   Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from
>   any peers. Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error:
>   failed to execute transaction
>   c662073e2142b94eea3fd971272b71ea276a2f25132f8a3a2c4b317b899ec48b:
>   error starting container: error starting container: Failed to generate
>   platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "npm ERR!
>   code EAI_AGAIN npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN npm ERR! request to
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/composer-common failed, reason: getaddrinfo
>   EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /root/.npm/_logs/2018-10-16T07_31_09_520Z-debug.log

What does this mean?
I also has installed a `composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna`. But if I run as above command. This is what I get.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the command `composer network start` you are asking Fabric to build and start a new 'Chaincode Docker Container'.  As part of the build of the new container there are some npm install commands, and it looks like your new container cannot access the npm registry.  This is likely a network proxy problem, so you need to create an 'npmrcfile' and pass that file on the command line of the `composer network install` command.

You should check the logs of the Docker Peer container to get more details of the error.  ( `docker logs peer...` )

There are 2 sections in the Composer Knowledge wiki which describe this in more detail - the formatting of the information is not very good, but it contains good details of solution.  [Section 1](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#cinstallissues) and [Section 2](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#startissues).

This [previous Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751259/error-in-starting-hyperledger-fabric-network-with-hyperledger-composer/49758354#49758354) has similar details.

Comment: how to create npmrcfile? do you have step-by-step guidelines?
after that, can you teach me how to pass the file on the command line of the composer network install command.